# Not able to fix my resolution of nextjs application it is varying for different sizes

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js

I have created a website using nextjs but the resolution is varyinh for different laptops or mobile view i want automatically to fix the resolutions

i have given based on my laptop resolution but when im seeing same website in different laptop it not alligned properly i need to be fixed the resolutions

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by 'the resolution is varying'? Have you ensured that your website is designed to be responsive?